# mod_wsgi cannot find my python packages?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

My django application loaded in Apache/mod_wsgi cannot find my external packages even though I specified it in sys.path?

The setup is as follows:

a) the external packages are in /var/www/site/my/python/config

b) the django website (with the settings.py file) is in /var/www/site/domain

c) the wsgi configuration file is:

```
import os, sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr

# Add the virtual Python environment site-packages directory to the path
import site
site.addsitedir('/var/www/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

# Avoid ``[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.python-eggs'`` messages
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/var/www/egg-cache'

# Add project directory to PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/var/www/site') # <---- THIS SHOULD FIND EXTERNAL PACKAGES?
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'domain.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

d) the settings.py file starts with the following:

```
print "prior to import"
from my.python.config import ConfigParser # <---- THIS EXIST AS INDICATED IN a), but fails!
print after to import"

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

....
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
prior to import
mod_wsgi (pid=3465): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/mod_wsgi/django.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
  self.load_middleware()
   File "/var/www/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
   File "/var/www/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
     self._setup()
   File "/var/www/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
   File "/var/www/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __init__
     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
 ImportError: Could not import settings 'domain.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named python.config
```

You can see that the settings.py file is attempted loaded as "prior to import" is printed, but the code failes on importing "my.python.config.ConfigParser". It seems to detect it as python.config instead though?

Any clues?

I have been tearing my hair out all day. Everything however works both in eclipse environment and by directly invoking 'django-admin.py runserver 80' after setting the python path and the django environment variables. I also verified that the python path is in sys.path.

I ran out of ideas, so ANY help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't   `print after to import" ` actually be `print "after to import" `  in the settings.py file.

Comment: Yes, it should. I must have accidentally deleted the quote while typing in the message on the line above? Thank for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Add at start of settings.py:

```
import my
print my.__file__
```

Validate that the path printed out is for the 'my' package you expect.

In other words, it could be picking up a different 'my' package because of such a package existing in multiple locations and the order of sys.path being wrong.

Also make sure you go read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

which talks about sys.path ordering issues.

Comment: Re-ordering the sys.path did not work according to your instructions and 'print my.__file__' did not print out, suggesting it is not the right package. However, I fail to see what else mod_wsgi could get confused with if both eclipse/pydev and the 'django-dadmin.py runserver' command both work.

I do use, mounting in /etc/fstab, but the original dir is what is set in apache. Any reason this wouldn't work with Apache?

Comment: If as you say 'print my.__file__' did not print out, then it couldn't have run. Did you restart Apache? It must print out something if the import of 'my' succeeded. Put a another print after 'import my' to see whether it even succeeded to import 'my' when done that way.

Comment: Alright, so I further narrowed it down. What I discovered is it works if I download the source tar file, and untar it to the target. However, if I untar it, create the top directories in the target and move the content over in the exact same layout. It doesn't work and mod_wsgi/apache cannot find the files. I'm assuming this is to do with permissions (although all files have world readability)? Is there a way to compare permissions on directory/file layout?

Comment: It isn't just file permissions which are important but directories. This extends to all directories back up to root directory. Go watch http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations as it explains permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `__init__.py` in all the subdirectories and its children of /var/www/site

when you access my.python.config, `__init__.py` needs to be there inside my directory, python directory and config directory.

Regarding permission, wsgi will be run as apache user (user you have specified in wsgi.conf).
Take care of it.

Comment: __init__.py existing and permissions set are all correct. Thank you for the suggestion.